# How to make ESP32 Camera module capture a photo triggered by Arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp32

as the title says, is it possible to trigger the ESP32 cam module via Arduino Uno? If so, how? Any response shall be very much appreciated. ❤️

Comment: Why do you need anArduino? The esp32 should be capable of triggering from its own gpio.

Comment: I am making a project that if the satisfied event happens (sensors monitoring connected to Arduino), then Arduino will trigger ESP32 camera module to capture

Comment: Why not connect the sensors to the ESP32 and ditch the Arduino?

Comment: But if you'd like to keep the Arduino, you could have the ESP32 Cam listen on a GPIO pin that's triggered/pulsed by Arduino every time an image needs to be captured. Note that the Arduino is a 5V device and the ESP32 is a 3.3V device. The GPIO should be converted to a suitable voltage level for the ESP32. BTW what should the ESP32 do with the image once it is captured?